# Android 7.1 Packages not available for Emulator for Linux 64 bit

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-7.1-nougat

I want to download packages of Android Nougat 7.1 for emulator but getting errors:

> All packages are not available for download!
>
> The following packages are not available:
>
> - Package id system-images;android-MNC;default;x86_64
> - Package id system-images;android-MNC;default;x86

[image: Screenshot of quoted error message]

What is the problem exactly? Anyone have tried with this?

Comment: MNC was the term for the M Developer Preview, which turned into Android 6.0/API Level 23/Marshmallow. What exactly are you doing in the SDK Manager that is triggering that "packages unavailable" dialog to appear?

Comment: I clicked on *Update System Images* @CommonsWare

Comment: Make sure that you are on Android Studio 2.2.2. If you are, perhaps [report a bug](http://b.android.com).